# from array to parseFloat ? calculations (part2)

Tags: javascript

**Info**

[1st part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54681665/swap-text-add-specific-word-html-php-code)

[Current online version](https://parrenmail.com/test/)  Link to my website

**Example input**

```
Copper Box v3;
S/N:25304;FW:1.07.12;

;a-b;a-GND;b-GND;
U=;0.74 V;3.23 V;0.48 V;
U~;0.03 V;0.02 V;0.02 V;
C;232.5 nF;11.87 nF;30.73 nF;
ISO;2.28 MΩ;237 kΩ;2.19 MΩ;
R;- -;

ΔC;- -;
Length;  - m;
```

**Desired output**

```
U=
A-B 0.74 V       //this cant be more then 5volts
A-G 3.23 V       //this cant be more then 5volts
B-G 0.48 V       //this cant be more then 5volts
U~
A-B 0.03 V       //this cant be more then 5volts
A-G 0.02 V       //this cant be more then 5volts
B-G 0.02 V       //this cant be more then 5volts
Cap
A-B 232.5 nF / 6.64 ff   //ab is always dividend by 35
A-G 11.87 nF / 0.27 ff   //ag is always dividend by 44
B-G 30.73 nF / 0.69 ff   //bg is always dividend by 44
difference
A-G en B-G =18.86 nF   //this number cant be bigger then 5
ISO
A-B 2.28 MOhm [X]   //if lower then 3Mohm thare is an error
A-G 237 KOhm [X]    //if lower then 3Mohm thare is an error
B-G 2.19 MOhm [X]   //if lower then 3Mohm thare is an error

difference
A-G en B-G =2.953 MOhm     // this number cant be bigger then 100 Mohm
```

**Current code**

```
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>input</th><th>&nbsp;&nbsp;</th><th>output</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><textarea style="background-color:#CACACA" id="source" cols="30" rows="22"></textarea></td> 
                            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                            <b><td><textarea style="background-color:#CACACA"  id="target" cols="30" rows="22" readonly></textarea></td></b>
                        </tr>
                    </table>


                    <script type="text/javascript">
                    document.getElementById("target").style.fontWeight = "600";
                    document.getElementById("source").style.fontWeight = "600";

document.querySelector("#source").addEventListener("input", function () {
    const lines = this.value
       .split(/^;/m) //split top ^ when a line starts at ; 
       .slice(1) 
       .join("")//;

       console.log(lines);

    var newlines = lines.replace(/MΩ/g, "MOhm" ) //find Ω and replace to Ohm 
   var newnewlines = newlines.replace(/kΩ/g, "KOhm [x] ") //find kΩ and replace to error's 
        .split("\n")//;

        console.log(newlines)//;
        console.log(newnewlines);

// var newnewlines = [];
newnewlines.push('item 1');
newnewlines.push('item 2');
newnewlines.push('item 3');
newnewlines.push('item 4');
newnewlines.push('item 5');
newnewlines.push('item 6');

  var ab = parseFloat(newnewlines[1]) < 5;
    if (ab < 5)  {
  ab = "[v] good";
} else {
  ab = "[x] error";
}

// log This is the place whare i break my brain
console.log(ab);

console.log(newnewlines[1]);
console.log(newnewlines[2]);
console.log(newnewlines[3]);
console.log(newnewlines[4]);
console.log(newnewlines[5]);
console.log(newnewlines[6]);


     const cols = newnewlines
       .shift()
       .toUpperCase() // makes A-B uppercase
       .split(";") //enter after;
       .filter(Boolean)
       .map(code => code.slice(0,3))//;

       console.log(cols);


    document.querySelector("#target").value =
        newnewlines.filter(line => /;\d/.test(line))
            .map(line => line.split(";").filter(Boolean))

                .map(
                    ([s, ...v]) => s + "\n" + 
                    v.map((value, i) => cols[i] + " " + value )
                    .join("\n")
                )

                 .join("\n");
});


                    </script><br><br>

  Test Text <br>
 <textarea style="background-color:#CACACA" cols="30" rows="22">

Device:ARGUS153;
S/N:55565;FW:1.80.00;

Copper Box v3;
S/N:25304;FW:1.07.12;

;a-b;a-GND;b-GND;
U=;0.74 V;3.23 V;0.48 V;
U~;0.03 V;0.02 V;0.02 V;
C;232.5 nF;11.87 nF;30.73 nF;
ISO;2.28 MΩ;237 kΩ;2.19 MΩ;
R;- -;

ΔC;- -;
Length;  - m;
</textarea>
```

**Question**

it has been a while and I have not finished with the puzzle I'm still learning how I can do it

I have a lot of information in the console but I still have not succeeded in calculating with it
I try to get the number from the array and then put the conditions into it

I'm not looking for someone who does everything for me I'm looking for how I can best learn this myself I do not understand anything about arrays since java script is new to me

- if you add code you would be so kind to explain // what you have done so that I can learn this

Comment: How did you arrive at the last number: `A-G en B-G = 2.953` ?

Comment: I think you intended `1.953` there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest a different approach than used in the first part you referred to Q&A. This is because you have calculations happening (differences) and checks (producing `[X]`), which means you have a stronger expectancy of what exactly the source would contain and in which order.

The code may defer the actual output format to a template literal. The code then only needs to extract the numbers (and units) from the input. The template literal, containing the formulas (subtraction) and conditional inclusion of `[X]`, will do the rest.

There is one tricky thing though: the solution must be aware of differences between unit of measures, so it performs the subtraction correctly even when one number is expressed in kΩ and another in MΩ. For this aspect I propose to create an object that indicates which units should be converted to a uniform unit, and with which factor. The solution defines just one such conversion, but you could extend it where needed. By consequence, the output will use the unified unit of measure, so 237 kΩ will appear as 0.237 MΩ in the output.

The code below assumes that the numbers of interest will always be followed by white space followed by a unit of measure (any sequence of characters, except semi-colon), followed by a semi-colon. There should be at least 12 of such sequences in the input. So actually, you can remove a lot of "noise" from the input and still get a correct output.

```js
// List of units that should be converted
const divisor = {
    kΩ: 1000 // Convert kΩ to MΩ
};

function refresh() {
    const u = (document.querySelector("#source").value
        // extract the numbers with their units:
        .match(/[\d.]+\s+[^;]+/g) || []) 
        // convert numbers to number type in uniform unit of measure:
        .map(m => +(parseFloat(m) / (divisor[m.split(/\s+/)[1]] || 1)).toString()); 
    
    document.querySelector("#target").innerHTML = 
        u.length < 12 ? "(not enough values)" :
`U=
A-B ${u[0]} V ${u[0]>5?"[X]":""}
A-G ${u[1]} V ${u[1]>5?"[X]":""}
B-G ${u[2]} V ${u[2]>5?"[X]":""}
U~
A-B ${u[3]} V ${u[3]>5?"[X]":""}
A-G ${u[4]} V ${u[4]>5?"[X]":""}
B-G ${u[5]} V ${u[5]>5?"[X]":""}
Cap
A-B ${u[6]} nF / ${(u[6]/35).toFixed(2)} ff
A-G ${u[7]} nF / ${(u[7]/44).toFixed(2)} ff
B-G ${u[8]} nF / ${(u[8]/44).toFixed(2)} ff
difference
A-G en B-G = ${u[8]-u[7]} nF ${u[8]-u[7]>5?"[X]":""}
ISO
A-B ${u[9]} MOhm ${u[9]<3?"[X]":""}
A-G ${u[10]} MOhm ${u[10]<3?"[X]":""}
B-G ${u[11]} MOhm ${u[11]<3?"[X]":""}
difference
A-G en B-G = ${(u[11]-u[10]).toFixed(3)} MOhm`;

}

document.querySelector("#source").addEventListener("input", refresh);

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
    document.querySelector("#source").innerHTML = `Copper Box v3;
S/N:25304;FW:1.07.12;

;a-b;a-GND;b-GND;
U=;0.74 V;3.23 V;0.48 V;
U~;0.03 V;0.02 V;0.02 V;
C;232.5 nF;11.87 nF;30.73 nF;
ISO;2.28 MΩ;237 kΩ;2.19 MΩ;
R;- -;

ΔC;- -;
Length;  - m;`;
    refresh();
});
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Paste output here: <button>Sample</button></th><th>Beautified:</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><textarea id="source" cols="30" rows="21"></textarea>
        </td>
        <td><textarea id="target" cols="30" rows="21" readonly></textarea></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Sweet @trincot ! took me week or so to try and understand the other code
This one I Totaly get !!

I found a little error so i made this work like this 

`A-G en B-G = ${ Math.abs((u[8]-u[7]).toFixed(2)) } nF ${Math.abs(u[8]-u[7])>5?"[X]":""}`

Makes negative number + and rounds them u are my idol now :)

Comment: Graag gedaan! Just one thing: it is a bit confusing to have a link to the answer code in your *question*. That will be confusing to future readers...

Comment: I am going to remove the link in a few weeks all the code i used is here :)

Comment: ? are u still here ?

Sinds this i am a populair guy at work making life better for every one 
Just a little question how can i add If els statemenst ?

`code
 ${u[0] and [1] and [2] =0?"if 0 show nothing":"if >0 Show 1 and 2 and 3 "  

  ${u[0]}
  ${u[1]}
  ${u[2]}
}
`

Comment: I don't really understand what you ask here, but you can code any expression inside those braces. Just use JS.

Comment: how can i make an if else statement ? Short like your code 

I wanna check if all 3 value's  are 00 and then leave out the part that has 00 
so if U is empty dont show 

`U=
A-B ${u[0]} V 
A-G ${u[1]} V 
B-G ${u[2]} V `

Comment: I got this working ` ${u[0] > 0 && u[1] > 0 && u[2] > 0 ? "dont do it":"do it"}`

But i cant wrap it around the next line ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean with "the next line".

Comment: Anyway you can chain conditions like `${ condition ? output : elsecondition2 ? output2 : elsecondition3 ? output3 : othercase_output }`

Comment: Oke maby i explane it wrong 

I try to show it in this link-->[link](https://parrenmail.com/test/) i wanna try if U = all 0 Dont show U =

Comment: You can do `${u[0] || u[1] || u[2] ? \`U= ...all the rest...\` : ""}`

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals